# Beginner GUI question, organising different "views"

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic

I've done plenty of programming before for CLI and the web, however recently I am getting into desktop GUI programming.

Most of the tutorials for GUI programming I found just explain the different controls you can use and leave it at that. Some of the better ones also skim over a few usability issues.

However, my problem is not with the APIs, or the theory but with my code.

How are you supposed to organise different views your application might have (e.g. a IM application has a login view, a contacts list view, a conversation view etc.).

Are these supposed to be different classes or different methods on one class?
Different panels that are hidden and revealed, or different windows altogether?

I'm hoping for answers as language agnostic as possible, but in case that's not possible, the languages/frameworks I am considering are Java/Swing or C#/WPF. However, if there's another language/framework that is significantly better for learning from, I would consider using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally each view will be a seperate class in a seperate file. The class will then most likely implement some base class like Window or Control.

As far as organization, if it's a simple app, put them in the root or in a UI folder. Or perhaps a Window folder and Controls folder.

If it's a large app with several views, than break them out into functionality, i.e. an IM folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with what Joshua said and as far as using different panels that are hidden and revealed, i've worked on old code and it's a nightmare to re-use (8000+ lines of Delphi 6!) so stick with different windows as much as possible!

Answer (score 0):

The generally recommended overall structure of the program is the model-view-controller ([MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)) type of structure.  So, first off, don't make the actual data part of the views, it goes into the model.  From here, since the only data in each view window is now almost entirely just layout information and what to do on an action (click, data display, etc), if these are different, they should probably be different classes.  If there's some general functionality that can be factored out, you can make this a base class and inherit from it, but in the end, windows with different functionalities should be different classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using one of the mainstream IDEs it will handle some of this work for you. The default will be a different class for each form. Hidden panels and tabbed interfaces are nice features but do yourself a favor and learn the ins and outs of embedding groups of controls into form. Some frameworks allow you to directly embed one form into another. Others have special containers that can be be embedded.

The point of these is to break up your functionality so you don't wind up with a bloated form class that's difficult to wade through.

I would also spend some time looking at some of the architectural patterns for keeping your business logic separate from your UI. Check out this [link](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/index.html) for a good starting point.